# PHP - Message: Undefined index but index exists

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I'm having a really strange problem. 
I have a little script that reads .csv file and store it in MySQL database. 
Uploading and reading file works fine (this is a csvreader library for CodeIgniter) - when I do:

```
$csvData = $this->csvreader->parse_csv($_FILES['csv_file']['tmp_name']);
   var_dump($csvData);
```

I'm getting proper results:

```
array(62) {
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["﻿email_address"]=>
    string(29) "info.bucharest@xxx.com"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["﻿email_address"]=>
    string(28) "cristina.banu@xxx.com"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    ["﻿email_address"]=>
    string(24) "office-ro@gxxx.com"
  }
```

Next thing I'm doing is just looping through

```
 foreach($csvData as $data_from_csv){
  $this->add_email_to_a_group($data_from_csv['email_address'], $contact_group_id);
 }
```

but in this moment I'm getting message:

> Severity: Notice Message: Undefined index: email_address

So in the loop var_dumping

```
var_dump($data_from_csv);
```

gives me this result:

```
array(1) { ["﻿email_address"]=> string(29) "info.bucharest@xxx.com" }
```

Whole project runs on shared hosting PHP 7.3 and the framework is CodeIgniter3.

What I am doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you certain that *every* record has an associated `email_address`? Id guess that there are 1 or more records in the set that are actually missing that property

Comment: You can test the above theory by adding this inside your loop: `if (!isset($data_from_csv['email_address'])) { var_dump($data_from_csv);}` and see what that spits out

Comment: Try this if it helps `foreach($csvData as $data_from_csv){
  $this->add_email_to_a_group($data_from_csv[0]['email_address'], $contact_group_id);
 }`

Comment: FWIW, its always best to check if a needed array index is present before trying to use it via something like: `if (isset($data_from_csv['email_address'])) { // do something with $data_from_csv['email_address'] here ... ;} `

Comment: ```var_dump()``` always creates confusion, use ```print_r``` so that you will get exact structure of your array.

Comment: Thanks, So what I did: cut down csv file to only 9 records then:
`$csvData = $this->csvreader->parse_csv($_FILES['csv_file']['tmp_name']);
print_r($csvData);
`
which returns:
`Array
(
 [1] => Array([email_address] => info.bucharest@xxx.com)
 [2] => Array([email_address] => cristina.banu@xxx.com)
 ...
`
adding this in the loop:
` if (!isset($data_from_csv['email_address'])) { print_r($data_from_csv);}`
displays:> Array ( [email_address] => info.bucharest@xxx.com )
but:>Message: Undefined index: email_address
Really confused 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are looping over a simple array, the var `$data_from_csv` will therefore contain the email address.

The error message is because there is in fact no `email_address` occurance in `$data_from_csv`

So change this code accordingly

```
foreach($csvData as $data_from_csv){
    $this->add_email_to_a_group($data_from_csv, $contact_group_id);
}
```

Or better still, name the variables so whats happening is clearer

```
foreach($csvData as $email){
    $this->add_email_to_a_group($email, $contact_group_id);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this is the solution. In my loop I'm checking if $data_from_csv is an array:
`if(is_array($data_from_csv)){print_r($data_from_csv);exit();}`
and it detect this variable as an array with key [email_address]:
`Array ( [email_address] => info.bucharest@als-europe.com )`

Comment: Something funny here, why do all your array dumps start at occurance `1` and not `0`

Comment: I think this is csvreader library - 0 element of this array is a "first cell" in the CVS document (generated from Excel) and it's used to create a key. If I'd add another column, i.e: company arrays would look like:
`array = ['email'=>'email@server', 'company'=>'company']`
and so 
Thanks

Comment: Ok so are you absolutely sure this is the line identified by the error? Most errors come with a line number and a filename

Comment: ... but - I added an extra loop to have array starting from 0 and it's still the same.
`Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: email_address
Filename: controllers/Contacts.php
Line Number: 140
Backtrace:
File: /home/myfreightforward/xxxx/application/controllers/Contacts.php`

`139:    foreach($new_array as $data_from_csv){
140:   $this->add_email_to_a_group($data_from_csv['email_address'], $contact_group_id);`

Answer (score 0):

Ok - I've got it.

What has happened in this case it may have something to do with character encoding ... I think.

For the test in my loop I added a check  `var_dump(array_keys($data_from_csv));` and it showed me that "email" was made of 8 characters rather than 5

```
foreach($csvData as $data_from_csv){
   var_dump(array_keys($data_from_csv)); 
// this was returnig (int)8 rather than expected (int)5 
   $this->add_email_to_a_group($data_from_csv['email'], $contact_group_id);
}
```

So ... now I'll be on the quest to make sure thtat uploaded file by user is properly encoded. 
Thanks